# Why shortValue() method are concrete but intValue() is abstract into java.lang.Number?

Tags: java, oop

I have read source code of `java.lang.Number` and I wondered why

1. `intValue()`
2. `longValue()`
3. `floatValue()`
4. `doubleValue()`

are abstract but

1. `shortValue()`
2. `byteValue()`

a concrete.

source code:

```
public abstract class Number implements java.io.Serializable {

      public abstract int intValue();

      public abstract long longValue();

      public abstract float floatValue();

      public abstract double doubleValue();

      public byte byteValue() {
        return (byte)intValue();
      }

     public short shortValue() {
        return (short)intValue();
      }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8742448824652078965L;
}
```

Why java founders have made it so?

I don't see big differencies between these method. Its seem as related.

**P.S.**

from Long class:

```
  public byte byteValue() {
        return (byte)value;
    }


    public short shortValue() {
        return (short)value;
    }


    public int intValue() {
        return (int)value;
    }


    public long longValue() {
        return (long)value;
    }


    public float floatValue() {
        return (float)value;
    }


    public double doubleValue() {
        return (double)value;
    }
```

from Integer class

```
public byte byteValue() {
        return (byte)value;
    }


    public short shortValue() {
        return (short)value;
    }


    public int intValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public long longValue() {
        return (long)value;
    }


    public float floatValue() {
        return (float)value;
    }

    public double doubleValue() {
        return (double)value;
    }
```

Hence we are see a lot of same code. I think `copy paste` development is bad but I think that Java founders have reasons for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation of the Number class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), the methods `byteValue` and `shortValue` were added first in JDK1.1. This is unlike the other "Value" methods which were already available in the very first JDK release.
My assumption is that those two methods were made concrete in order to keep compatibility with existing (also non-standard) subclasses of `Number`, which would otherwise have been broken by the addition of new abstract methods in the superclass.

Comment: It is looks like truth.

Answer (score 1):

`byte` and `short` are the lesser memory consuming versions, and since `intValue` is `abstract`, the implementation of `intValue` can be used for the byte and short. I think that's why they should have done it like that.

Comment: I don't understand how to connects  memory consuming and abstractness

Comment: abstract is used to leave the implementation of the method to the class that extends `Number` and since `intValue` is abstract, the implementation of `intValue` can be used for `byte` and `short`, as they are nothing but shorter versions of `int`

Comment: I don't understand full chain. **intValue is abstract, the implementation of intValue can be used for byte and short, as they are nothing but shorter versions of int** == **longValue is abstract, the implementation of longValue can be used for int and byte and  short, as they are nothing but shorter versions of long**

Comment: @gstackoverflow true, but `byte` and `short` are less used so a default implementation (that is mostly useless) reduces the burden on classes implementing `Number`.

Comment: @Boris the Spider I really don't understand this answer(

Answer (score 0):

@Anirudh sir, Small confirmation as you said that byte and short method are consuming the lesser memory to store the value, but it is not the right way to perform an operations by taking the same variable.. Because the byte variable will return you the negative value.

//As per (step-1)Integer is the wrapper class object which is stored with 100000 value above range of byte. But the memory usage is less compare to int memory consumstion or range. because the int range is up to 600000 or smthng. remaining is waste of memory(apart from 100000), so you said that the int value(100000) if we convert to byte like(step-2) the more usage of memory will get reduced. But the value get stored inside the "b" variable is negative value. So here we cannot perform any operation with the original value(100000). Please suggest me if i am in wrong thought.

step-1:-
Integer io=new Integer(100000);

step-2:-
byte b=io.byteValue();